# How do I convert a List[Option[(A, List[B])]] to the Option[(A,List[B])]? (Basically retrieve Option[X] from List[Option[X]])

Tags: scala, data-structures, collections, for-comprehension

I have a List of `“rules”` tuples as follows:

`val rules = List[(A, List[B])]`, where `A` and `B` are two separate case-classes

For the purposes of my use-case, I need to convert this to an `Option[(A, List[B])]`. The `A` case class contains a property `id` which is of type `Option[String]`, based on which the tuple is returned.

I have written a function `def findRule(entryId: Option[String])`, from which I intend to  return the tuple `(A, List[B])` whose `A.id = entryId` as an Option. So far, I have written the following snippet of code:

```
def findRule(entryId: Option[String]) = {
    for {
        ruleId <- rules.flatMap(_._1.id) // ruleId is a String
        id <- entryId   // entryId is an Option[String]
    } yield {
        rules.find(_ => ruleId.equalsIgnoreCase(id))    // returns List[Option[(A, List[B])]
    }
}
```

This snippet returns a `List[Option[(A, List[B])]` but I can’t figure out how to retrieve just the Option from it. Using `.head()` isn’t an option, since the `rules` list may be empty. Please help as I am new to Scala.

**Example** (the real examples are too large to post here, so please consider this representative example):

`val rules = [(A = {id=1, ….}, B = [{B1}, {B2}, {B3}, …]), (A={id=2, ….}, B = [{B10}, {B11}, {B12}, …]), …. ]` (`B` is not really important here, I need to find the tuple based on the `id` element of case-class `A`)

Now, suppose `entryId = Some(1)`

After the `findRule()` function, this would currently look like:

`[Some((A = {id=1, …}, B = [{B1}, {B2}, {B3}, …]))]`

I want to return:

`Some((A = {id=1, …}, B = [{B1}, {B2}, {B3}, …]))` , ie, the Option within the List returned (currently) from `findRule()`

Comment: Hello. In the title you say *"How do I convert a `List[Option[(A, List[B])]]` ..."* but in the body you say `val rules = List[(A, List[B])]`. Which one is it?

Comment: Also could you please include an example with an actual list, and what it would look like once converted? Please make the list small, maybe like three elements.

Comment: Hi, yes, the `rules` val is a `List[(A, List[B])]`. I then convert the `rules` to a `List[Option[(A, List[B])]` in the `findRule()` function (intending to convert it just to the `Option`, but that is what I can't figure out). 
I want to convert the result of this `findRule()` function to `Option[(A, List[B])]`.

Comment: You have a list that you want to convert to a single element. That means you need to pick an element, or reduce the list according to some logic. Assuming you want to pick an element; which element do you want to pick? If you just want the first element, you can probably use `headOption.flatten`.

Comment: This seems to be just a `collectFirst`? The question is hard to follow since it adds too many unnecessary details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you're trying to pick a single item from your list based on some conditional, which means you'll probably want to start with `rules.find`. The problem then becomes how to express the predicate function that you pass to `find`.

From my read of your question, the conditional is

> The `id` on the `A` part of the tuple needs to match the `entryId` that was passed in elsewhere

```scala
def findRule(entryId: Option[String]) = 
  rules.find { case (a, listOfB) => entryId.contains(a.id) }
```

The `case` expression is just nice syntax for dealing with the tuple. I could have also done

```scala
rules.find { tup => entryId.contains(tup._1.id) }
```

The `contains` method on Option roughly does "if I'm a Some, see if my value equals the argument; if I'm a None, just return false and ignore the argument". It works as a comparison between the `Option[String]` you have for `entryId` and the plain `String` you have for `A`'s `id`.

Your first attempt didn't work because `rules.flatMap` got you a `List`, and using that after the `<-` in the for-comprehension means another `flatMap`, which keeps things as a List.

Answer (score 1):

A variant that I personally prefer is

```scala
def findRule(entryId: Option[String]): Option[(A, List[B])] = {
  entryId.flatMap { id =>
    rules.find { case (a, _) => a.id == id }
  }
}
```

In the case where `entryId` is `None`, it just immediately returns `None`. If you start with `rules.find`, then it will iterate through all of the rules and check each one even when `entryId` is `None`. It's unlikely to make any observable performance difference if the list of rules is small, but I also find it more intuitive to understand.